# Register double click in the context of an if else condition

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I pick up a double click event in the context of an if/else statement?

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ///
        }
        else if () { // if double click condition goes here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `MouseDoubleClick` event instead:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        // Right button was not double-clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That `else if` won't never be able to catch the `DoubleClick`, you have to handle the `DataGridView.DoubleClick` not the `MouseClick`:

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //handle here...
}
//Code to register the DoubleClick event:
dataGridView1.DoubleClick += dataGridView1_DoubleClick;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.Clicks == 2)
        {
            // it is double click
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use datagridview double click event instead

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

If you need essentially to check for double click in mouse click event then you can create a global bool variable and set to true in double click event

```
bool _Double = false;
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Double = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ///
    }
    else if (_Double) {
    }
}
```